# Accessing elements of a nested structures

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, compiler-errors, member-access

when I execute the following code I get an error message for this line `scanf("%s",A.(T+i)->CNE)`

error message :  `expected identifier before '(' token|`

can I know what is the problem? thanks in advance.

```
typedef struct date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
}date;
typedef struct Student
{
    char CNE[10];
    char FirstName[30];
    char LastName[30];
    date BD;
    float Grades[6];
}Student;
typedef struct Class
{
    Student T[1500];
    int dim;
}Class;
Class input(Class A)
{
    int i=A.dim;
    printf("Enter the student CNE : ");
    scanf("%s",A.(T+i)->CNE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that can be after a `.` operator is a member name. It cannot be an expression such as `(T+i)`.

Normally, to access element `i` of the member `T`, one would use `A.T[i]`, and then its `CNE` member would be `A.T[i].CNE`.

Presumably, you have been studying pointer arithmetic and are interested in accessing `A.T[i]` using pointers. In this case, `A.T + i` will give the address of element `i` of `A.T`. Then `(A.T + i)->CNE` will be the `CNE` member of that element. (Observe that `A.T` is an array, but, in this expression, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. So `A.T + i` is equivalent to `&A.T[0] + i`, which says to take the address of `A.T[0]` and advance it by `i` elements.)

Answer (score 1):

`(T+i)` is not a member of the structure `Class`, so you cannot use `A.(T+i)`.

It seems `A.(T+i)->CNE` should be `A.T[i].CNE`.

Also it is suspicious that the modified `A` is discarded at returning from the function `input`. It seems you forgot to write `return A;`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean either

```
scanf("%s",A.T[i].CNE);
```

or

```
scanf("%s", ( A.T + i )->CNE );
```

That is in the used by you expression

```
A.(T+i)->CNE
```

the dot operator expects an identifier instead of an expression.

And your function return nothing though its return type is not `void`.

The function could be declared and defined for example the following way

```
void input(Class *A)
{
    int i = A->dim;
    printf("Enter the student CNE : ");
    scanf( "%s", ( A->T + i )->CNE );
}
```